# How to Nest INNER JOINs in LEFT JOINs

Tags: sequelize.js

Imagine I have an association table [PersonPhones] between my [Persons] and [Phones] table.  And I run the following query:

### Sequelize

```
Person.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: PersonPhones,
    required: false,
    include: [{
      model: Phones,
      required: true
    }]
  }]
});
```

### Question:

What I would assume I would get would be the equivalent to Query 1 below, which returns 4 rows.  But what I get is Query 2, which returns just 2 rows.  Is there a way to force Sequelize to nest the INNER JOIN under the LEFT JOIN?

---

### SQL

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Persons (id INT, name VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #Phones (id INT, number VARCHAR(20))
CREATE TABLE #PersonPhones (personId INT, phoneId INT) 

INSERT INTO #Persons VALUES (1,'Adam'), (2, 'Bob'), (3, 'Carl')
INSERT INTO #Phones VALUES (1, '555-1234'), (2, '555-2345'), (3, '555-3456')
INSERT INTO #PersonPhones VALUES (1,1), (1,3), (2, 4)

-- The following are not the same queries

-- Query 1
SELECT *
FROM #Persons p
LEFT JOIN #PersonPhones pp 
    INNER JOIN #Phones ph ON ph.id = pp.phoneID
    ON pp.personID = p.ID

-- Query 2
SELECT *
FROM #Persons p
LEFT JOIN #PersonPhones pp ON pp.personID = p.ID
INNER JOIN #Phones ph ON ph.id = pp.phoneID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with one of the creators of the library, I'm told nested joins are not a supported feature.  [I have created an issue with their GitHub project](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10695).  Feel free to comment or follow from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-- Query 1
SELECT *
FROM #Persons p
LEFT JOIN (
    select * from #PersonPhones pp 
    INNER JOIN #Phones ph ON ph.id = pp.phoneID
    ) x ON x.personID = p.ID
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but this is a Sequelize.js question.

Comment: @astangelo Sorry, didn't realize. :-(